# Call onSharedPreferenceChanged() method from AlertDialog

Tags: android

I am Having an Alert Dialog which has a edit text box and a password box.
On pressing positive button of Alert Dialog I want to save data once entered in it to my Preference `login_prefs,xml`. Can anyone please help me to call onSharedPreferencesChanged method so that I can save my values in it.
I tried many ways but I failed to achieve it.
Also can any one help me to retrieve the default value from the same

Thanks

Code:

```
public class LoginCredsHandlerDialog extends SherlockDialogFragment {
String Tag = getClass().getSimpleName(), idString, passString , idKey = "loginId", passKey = "pass";
View view;
EditText id, pass;
SharedPreferences loginPrefs;
OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listen;
final Context context = getSherlockActivity();
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder loginMenu = new AlertDialog.Builder(getSherlockActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflate = getSherlockActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    view = inflate.inflate(R.layout.prefs_layout, null);
    loginMenu.setView(view);
    id = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.loginId);
    pass = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.loginPass);
    Log.i(Tag, "before prefreneces class");
    new SaveData();
    loginPrefs  = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getSherlockActivity());
    Log.i(Tag, "linked to prefrences class");
    Log.i(Tag, "Got String Value");
    loginMenu.setTitle("Login Prefrences Menu");
    loginMenu.setCancelable(false);
    loginMenu.setPositiveButton("Save", new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Log.i(Tag, "Save Key Pressed");
            new SaveData().onSharedPreferenceChanged(loginPrefs, idKey);
            Log.i(Tag, "Values Saved");
        }
    });
    loginMenu.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            LoginCredsHandlerDialog.this.getDialog().cancel();
        }
    });
    return loginMenu.create();
}
public class SaveData extends SherlockPreferenceActivity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    SharedPreferences spf;
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.log_prefs);
        loginPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getSherlockActivity());
        idString = loginPrefs.getString(idKey, "");
        passString = loginPrefs.getString(passKey, "");
        if(idString.equals("") || passString.equals("")){
            idString = id.toString();
            passString = pass.toString();
        }

        id.setText(idString);
        pass.setText(passString);
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Set up a listener whenever a key changes
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
                .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // Unregister the listener whenever a key changes
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
                .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        if(key==idKey){
            Log.i(Tag, "saver");
            Preference pref = findPreference(key);
            pref.setDefaultValue(sharedPreferences.getString(key, ""));
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You do not call onSharedPreferencesChanged() function, it is call back function will be called when somebody change preference.

When you commit you login preference onSharedPreferencesChanged() will get called.

You can save value in preference like this:

```
loginPrefs.edit().putString("login_prefs", VALUE).commit();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Where exactly should I place this code.

Comment: I believe you just want to store value in preference, for that: 
Read the edit text VALUE and commit to preference.
If you just want to store than you do not need any listener code.

`@Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Log.i(Tag, "Save Key Pressed");
            loginPrefs.edit().putString("login_prefs", VALUE).commit();
            Log.i(Tag, "Values Saved");
        }`

Comment: Actually I want to read the values from the preferences first..if the values in the preferences are null then save the new values in. I have tried the code you said but still the values don't get saved.

Comment: in you code    `loginPrefs.edit().putString("login_prefs", VALUE).commit();`  will it be `login_prefs` or `idKey` ?

Comment: Please read the documentation they have API to read values. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html